# Return media queries with mixins

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I want to create a mixin which would return a normal css block as well as a media query css block.
The `$base-width` would be `100vw` for mobile devices and `33vw` for desktops.

Example Usage:

```css
.app {
    @include responsive {
        width: $base-width/2;
    }
}
```

and it would basically compile to:

```css
.app {
  width: 100vw/2;     // for mobile devices
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    width: 33vw/2;    // for desktop since $base-width: 33vw;
  }
}
```

*The left-hand property could be anything, not always `width`.*

Is it possible? What could be the possible closest solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 @mixin breakpoint($point) {
    @media (min-width: $point) { @content; } 
}

.app {
  width: 100vw/2;     // for mobile devices
  @include breakpoint(992px){
     width: 33vw/2; // for desktop since
  }
}
```

This is a flexible way to do it.